# 1 pixel offset at certain window widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

I get a really interesting glitch in both Safari and Firefox with the following JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/68gcy2gp/

You have to click on the red box to toggle the blue overlay.

I have two left floated relative positioned `li` elements with a width of `32%` plus `1%` right margin. I then put a `div` element positioned `absolute` with top/left 0 over the `li` element. The width of this `div` will be set to the same width the 32% `li` has (via jQuery).

On certain screen widths I get then a 1px glitch (too long or too short). Like this screenshot shows it:

[image: 1px glitch from JS fiddle example]

How can I prevent this glitch?

Comment: The fiddle you posted looks nothing like the image you posted in the question.

Comment: @Pointy: For me it does on 1920 x 1200 px in firefox

Comment: @Tyr so you click that jsfiddle link and you see a blue box on top of a red box?

Comment: [This is what I see](http://s25.postimg.org/rf7j8n2xb/this.png).

Comment: @ Pointy: No, it's not on the top, it's an overlay but with 1px more width than the red box. @ TiMESPLiNTER: This could be a rounding issue by CSS relative to the dimensions of the elements in your code. One option to avoid this is using pixel based dimensions like width: 250px

Comment: i tried to reproduce your error in firefox and could not. and you do mean to wide or to thin right?

Comment: You have to resize the result area. At some widths there happens this shown in my screenshot above at some everything is fine. I also guess it has to do with rounding issues because of the percentage widths. I like to know if there is any known hack/workaround for this. (Except fixed widths as mentioned by @Tyr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as an official answer:

jQuery .width() or .innerWidth() is rounding the width of subpixel to the next integer value either with floor or ceil, depending on the value. To avoid that you can use some raw javascript:

```
$('.person').each(function() {
    var front = $(this).find('.front');
    var back = $(this).find('.back');
    var link = $('<a href="#"></a>');

    link.on('click', function() {
        var width = $(front)[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
        back.innerWidth(width);
        back.toggle();
    });

    $(this).wrap(link);
    back.hide();
});
```

The following function is for checking pixel errors by resizing the window with active overlay:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('li').each(function() {
        var back = $(this).find('.back');
        var width = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
        back.width(width);    
    });
});
```

If you use .innerWidth() instead of getBoundingClientRect() you will see the error you have stated.

Comment: Awesome. A perfect solution. Thank you very much! Should I report this "issue" to jQuery or are the devs of jQuery aware of this? Because to me it looks like a bug.